Setting KVM Nested Virtualization: kvm-amd, or kvm_amd?
I am setting KVM Nested Virtualization for my AMD bare metal CPU. I see there are both kvm-amd and kvm_amd description in guides (search /etc/modprobe.d on pages):

https://linux-kvm.org/page/Nested_Guests
https://docs.redhat.com/en/documentation/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/configuring_and_managing_virtualization/creating-nested-virtual-machines_configuring-and-managing-virtualization#creating-a-nested-virtual-machine-on-amd_creating-nested-virtual-machines
https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/using-nested-virtualization-in-kvm/
https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.9/virt/kvm/running-nested-guests.html
https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/how-to-enable-nested-virtualization

Which word is correct here?
options kvm-amd nested=1 or options kvm_amd nested=1

They’re both correct, hyphens and underscores are equivalent in kernel command-line parameters:

Hyphens (dashes) and underscores are equivalent in parameter names, so:
log_buf_len=1M print-fatal-signals=1

can also be entered as:
log-buf-len=1M print_fatal_signals=1


